# Redux chaining asynchronous actions with redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Say there are 2 date picker objects that corresponds to start date and end date.

These exist as states, so in order to set them, you would have to call setStartDate or setEndDate which then reducer picks up and simply sets the states.

Say I also have an async action that Is called getHugeListFromServer with (REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE) and is called with parameters getHugeListFromServer(startDate, endDate).

Everytime a user picks a date, I want to call the getHugeList function and update the list. If I do something like this, it does not work because the backend action is called before the date variable is set by reducer.

example_container.jsx

```
 class example extends React.Component {
... Methods
  onChangeStartDate (startDate) {
    this.props.setStartDate(startDate);
    this.props.getHugeListFromServer(startDate,  this.props.example.endDate);
  } 
  // similar method for endDate. 
}
```

I have redux thunk installed and it still doesn't help my problem. I thought about having the reducer for setDate actions to return a promise and resolve it in the container before calling the backend action, but I bet there's a better way to go about this.

Can someone lay a hand? Thanks!

Comment: Inside your **getHugeListFromServer** function, you can call the **setStartDate** and also execute the default functionality.

Comment: That doesn't really match with the name of getHugeListFromServer though.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought about having the reducer for setDate actions to return a promise and resolve it in the container before calling the backend action, but I bet there's a better way to go about this.

I don't think that sounds unreasonable at all. In fact, with redux, that would probably be completely fine and possibly preferred.

However, if you want, you could look into some lifecycle methods of components such as `componentWillUpdate()` - this will call each time your state is about to be updated. So you could keep your handler as is but just remove `this.props.getHugeListFromServer(...)` from it and put it inside of the`componentWillUpdate()` hook - check the documentation link below to see examples of how to implement it.

https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/tapping_into_componentwillupdate.html

Comment: Then what really is the purpose of redux-thunk? Isn't it supposed to resolve all this kind of async reducer issues for me?